# How to get the data from the fragment in viewpager when dynamically added fragments are swiped in swipeable tabs?

Tags: android

I am working on an app that includes shopping feature and items are added to cart.
I have navigation drawer. In that, I have my first fragment called as "POSFragment" in which I have implemented a viewpager as data to be shown in the form of swipeable tabs. The data will be inflated dynamically. So, I have used PagerTabStrip and a viewpager. There is a common fragment called "MenuDetailFragment" in which data will be inflated dynamically through a webservice. the adapter for this fragment is "MenuPagerAdapter". Now, In this fragment the data will shown in listview. In Listview in each row items can be incremented or decremented using plus and minus Buttons in each row. Between these button there is textview where the quantity will be displayed correspondingly. I have used a Linkedhashmap on both buttons so, the items along with the quantity is saved in linkedhashmap and then in Sharedpreferences. It's working fine till now. The issue occurs when I swipe in the View pager and next fragment appears and When I click on increment button or decrement button on item there. In shared preferences, It starts saving the current fragment items and previous fragment data is not there anymore. I have already used the "yourcustomviewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3)" So, I can see the selected items with the quantities whe I swipe to and fro but the data i stored in sharedpreferences using Linkedhashmap is not there instead current  fragment's data is saved. I want that the new data is added to previous data and data in all the fragments should persist. Is there a way to do so? I have been facing this issue for quite a long time.
Here are some screenshots and relevant code snippet.

```
public class PosFragment extends Fragment {
private ViewPager viewPager;
View rootview;
String code;
String name;
String desc;
String rate;
String key;
Button viewCartBtn;
static TextView displayPrice;
static TextView noOfItemsInCart;
RippleView rippleView;
//private sendPosition pos;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
Log.e("oncreateview", "called");
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pos_fragment_layout, container, false);
initViews();
new AsyncTaskGetMenu().execute();
return rootview;
}
public void initViews() {
Log.e("init", "called");
viewPager = (ViewPager) rootview.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
Button viewCartButton = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_btn);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
viewCartBtn = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.view_cart_btn);
AppMethods.setGlametrixBoldFont(getActivity(), viewCartBtn);
displayPrice = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.textView_totalprice_cart);
noOfItemsInCart = (TextView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.cart_items_quantity);
viewCartBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewCartActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.SUBTOTAL, Integer.parseInt(displayPrice.getText().toString()));
startActivity(intent);
}
});
LinearLayout itemsInCartLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.ll_items_in_cart);
itemsInCartLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ViewCartActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(AppConstants.SUBTOTAL, Integer.parseInt(displayPrice.getText().toString()));
startActivity(intent);
}
});
}
```

---

```
This is "MenuDetailFragment" class
public class MenuDetailFragment extends Fragment {
View rootview;
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<MenuHeadingDetailsModel> menuheadingDetailList;
private Communicate comm;
LinkedHashMap<String, ViewCartDetailsModel> viewCartDetailsModelMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
ViewCartDetailsModel viewCartDetailsModel;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list, container, false);
InitializeViews();
return rootview;
}
public void InitializeViews() {
listView = (ListView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.menu_items_list);
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
menuheadingDetailList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(AppConstants.MENU_KEY);
listView.setAdapter(new MenuAdapter(getActivity(), menuheadingDetailList));[enter image description here][1]
```

---

This is"MenuPagerAdapter" class

```
public class MenuPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
List<MenuModel> menu;
public MenuPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<MenuModel> menuList) {
super(fm);
this.menu = menuList;
}
@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
return menu.get(position).getHeading().toString();
}
private List<MenuHeadingDetailsModel> getMenuHeadingDetails(int pos) {
return this.menu.get(pos).getMenuHeadingDetailList();
}
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
Fragment fragment = new MenuDetailFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList(AppConstants.MENU_KEY, (ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) getMenuHeadingDetails(position));
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
return fragment;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return menu.size();
}
@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
if (observer == null) {
super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}
}
@Override
public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object)
{
Log.e("destroyitem","called");
}
}
class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
//ViewHolder holder;
Context context;
List<MenuHeadingDetailsModel> myItems = new ArrayList<>();
Button buttonPlus, buttonMinus;
int totalAmount = 0;
int pagePosition;
public MenuAdapter(Context context, List<MenuHeadingDetailsModel> myItems) {
this.context = context;
this.myItems = myItems;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
return myItems.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
return myItems.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
final LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
viewHolder.codeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_code);
viewHolder.nameText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
AppMethods.setGlametrixBoldFont(getActivity(), viewHolder.nameText);
viewHolder.descText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_desc);
viewHolder.rateText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_rate);
viewHolder.textViewNoOfItems = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_of_items);
buttonMinus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_minus);
buttonPlus = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_plus);
final MenuHeadingDetailsModel menu = myItems.get(position);
viewHolder.codeText.setText(menu.getCode());
viewHolder.nameText.setText(menu.getItemName());
viewHolder.descText.setText(menu.getDescription());
viewHolder.rateText.setText(menu.getRate());
viewHolder.textViewNoOfItems.setText("" + menu.getQuantity());
buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
MenuHeadingDetailsModel menuList = myItems.get(position);
menuList.setQuantity(menuList.getQuantity() + 1);
myItems.set(position, menuList);
int itemRate = Integer.parseInt(myItems.get(position).getRate());
int itemQuan = menuList.getQuantity();
String code = menuList.getCode();
String name = menuList.getItemName();
int totalAmountPerItem = itemQuan * itemRate;
viewCartDetailsModel = new ViewCartDetailsModel(code, name, itemQuan, itemRate);
viewCartDetailsModelMap.put(viewCartDetailsModel.getCode(), viewCartDetailsModel);
Log.e("hashmap", "size" + viewCartDetailsModelMap.size());
Gson gson = new Gson();
String hashMapToString = gson.toJson(viewCartDetailsModelMap);
AppPreferences.saveDataInSharedpreferences(getActivity(), AppConstants.VIEW_ITEMS_INT_CART_KEY, hashMapToString);
totalAmount += itemRate;
int amount = totalAmount;
onButtonPressedForAmount(amount);
notifyDataSetChanged();
int quan = 0;
TextView tv;
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
View view = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_of_items);
quan = quan + Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
}
onButtonClickedForQuantity(quan);
}
}
);
buttonMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
MenuHeadingDetailsModel menuList = myItems.get(position);
if ((menuList.getQuantity() - 1) >= 0) {
menuList.setQuantity(menuList.getQuantity() - 1);
myItems.set(position, menuList);
int itemRate = Integer.parseInt(myItems.get(position).getRate());
int itemQuan = menuList.getQuantity();
String code = menuList.getCode();
String name = menuList.getItemName();
//int totalAmountPerItem = itemQuan * itemRate;
viewCartDetailsModel = new ViewCartDetailsModel(code, name, itemQuan, itemRate);
if (itemQuan == 0) {
viewCartDetailsModelMap.remove(code);
} else {
viewCartDetailsModelMap.put(viewCartDetailsModel.getCode(), viewCartDetailsModel);
}
Gson gson = new Gson();
String hashMapToString = gson.toJson(viewCartDetailsModelMap);
AppPreferences.saveDataInSharedpreferences(getActivity(), AppConstants.VIEW_ITEMS_INT_CART_KEY, hashMapToString);
if (totalAmount > 0) {
totalAmount -= itemRate;
Log.e("totalamount", "minus" + totalAmount);
int amount = totalAmount;
onButtonPressedForAmount(amount);
}
} else {
menuList.setQuantity(0);
myItems.set(position, menuList);
}
notifyDataSetChanged();
int quan = 0;
TextView tv;
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getCount(); i++) {
View view = listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_no_of_items);
quan = quan + Integer.parseInt(tv.getText().toString());
}
onButtonClickedForQuantity(quan);
}
}
);
return convertView;
}
public void onButtonPressedForAmount(int userData) {
if (comm != null) {
comm.sendAmount(userData);
}
}
public void onButtonClickedForQuantity(int quantity) {
if (comm != null) {
comm.sendQuantity(quantity);
}
}
class ViewHolder {
TextView nameText;
TextView codeText;
TextView descText;
TextView rateText;
TextView textViewNoOfItems;
}
 }
//For settings fonts to the alert diaolog for customization of items
//public void setGlametrixBoldFont(TextView textView) {
//Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/GlametrixBold.otf");
//textView.setTypeface(typeface);
// }
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
super.onAttach(activity);
try {
comm = (Communicate) activity;
} catch (Exception e) {
AppMethods.getStackTrace(e);
}
}
public interface Communicate {
public void sendAmount(int amount);
public void sendQuantity(int quantity);
}
//    public void getPosition(int Position) {
//
//        int pagePosition = Position;
//        Log.e("pos", " " + pagePosition);
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your current fragment inside view pager by following below way

```
SampleFragment sampleFr = (SampleFragment) viewPager.getAdapter().instantiateItem(viewPager, 0);
```

Now you can access any data you want using that fragment.

For the first time adding fragments in view pager do like below way.

```
        BaseFragment frTimeLine = (BaseFragment) Fragment.instantiate(this, SampleFragment.class.getName());
        fragments.add(frTimeLine);
        BaseFragment frEarnTiqs = (BaseFragment) Fragment.instantiate(this, SampleFragment1.class.getName());
        fragments.add(frEarnTiqs);


        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getResources(), fragments);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Comment: My fragments are added dynamically.The data of my first page is stored in sharedprefences but when i swipe to the next page and enter the quantity the shared pref start saving the new data of second fragment and the data of previous frag is not there..I want that the data should keep on adding there for all the pages being swipped.Is there a way to save or retain the data globally.